# On form submit fails to save data to database, WP Settings API

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to save custom field values to `wp_options` database table using a custom plugin.

On my front-end:

[image: plugin admin]

My database:

[image]

As you can see from the database the `theme_options` entry is there but the `option_value` field is missing some information namely the data item `foo` from my form submission?

My code is over here:
https://github.com/1cookie/work/tree/master/wp-content/plugins/fi-theme-settings

Can you see what I'm doing wrong and why the value doesn't get entered?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your plugin on github and don't see anywhere in the code where you are updating the setting using the `update_option()` function.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

Comment: True, but if I've just activated the plugin and there are no values in `wp_options` associated with the aforementioned plugin then I wouldn't be updating the db - I'd be inserting. Surely?

Comment: The title of your post is "On form submit fails to save data to database" and the question you asked is "Can you see what I'm doing wrong and why the value doesn't get entered?"

When you submit the form, whatever is entered in the company name field is not saved to the database because there is nothing in your code that is updating the option_value field.

Comment: Interestingly enough nor does this http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/ article which happens to be the tutorial I was following originally. What have I learned from all this? Always go to the WP codex docs first rather than trying to de-tangle a poorly written tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can change an option like this:

```
$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
update_option( 'theme_options', $company_name );
```